# Windows Azure: FTP issue When Connecting to Website

Tags: azure

I am trying to connect to website in win azure using filezilla. It connected fine for few minutes and I was able to upload the files. But then it stopped working. I am getting this message:

Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (137,117,88,16,40,32).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
Response:   550 The network connection was aborted by the local system. 
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing

I have tried setting transfer mode to ACTIVE and few other suggestions, but nothing seems to work. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a time-out issue on the server. You will need to tell your FTP client to keep the connection alive so that it doesn't start a second connection while the first connection is still alive.

To set this in FileZilla client, go to Edit, Settings, Connection, FTP, and check "Send FTP keep-alive commands" checkbox.

For more detailed explanation of the problem, visit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wats/archive/2013/12/13/setting-up-a-passive-ftp-server-in-windows-azure-vm.aspx Scroll towards the bottom and read the "Points to consider from Azure SLB perspective" section.

I had the same problem with my FTP on Azure (getting 550 errors) and checking the "Send FTP keep-alive commands" checkbox above solved my problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The error message:

> Response: 550 The network connection was aborted by the local system

Suggests that there is an error in your local network.

This error is not within Windows Azure, but within your local network (and appears to only be triggered by FileZilla). Contact your system administrator or Internet Service Provider. Also, please try first solving the problem yourself using something like [this](https://www.google.bg/search?q=passive+ftp+550+The+network+connection+was+aborted+by+the+local+system.&oq=passive+ftp+550+The+network+connection+was+aborted+by+the+local+system).

Comment: I get this error and ı used this after fixed http://myprogrammingzone.blogspot.com.tr/2015/06/filezilla-data-connection-could-not-be.html#.WUEK0ZDyhhE